# How would I count the number of digits to the right of the decimal in a floating point column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, digits

I have table with Latitudes and Longitudes that are stored as floating points.  How would I count the number of digits to the right of the decimal in the Latitude column?  The data would look something like this:

```
    DECLARE @MyData TABLE (ID, Latitude float, Longitude float)
    INSERT @MyData

    SELECT 'A', 33.11, -55.2235 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 33.6407760431,-87.0002760543 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 42.2997,-70.9081;
```

and I would want this in

```
    ID    |   LatitudeNumberOfDigits
     A    |    2
     B    |   10
     C    |    4
```

I was trying to convert it to text and split it up using a . as a delimiter but the CONVERT did not work as anticipated.  It rounded to four significant digits

```
    SELECT ID, Latitude, Longitude, 
    CONVERT(varchar(max),[Latitude]) AS LatText 
    FROM @MyData
```

Gave me

```
     ID Latitude    Longitude        LatText
     A  33.11           -55.2235         33.11
     B  33.6407760431   -87.0002760543   33.6408
     C  42.2997         -70.9081         42.2997
```

Thanks !

Comment: Since the original design for kilometres was 10,000 km = distance N Pole to Equator, 10,000 km ≈ 90°, so there are about 111 km per degree, so 1×10⁻¹¹ degrees ≈ 111×10⁻¹¹ km ≈ 1110×10⁻¹² km ≈ 1.11×10⁻⁹ km ≈ 1×10⁻⁶ m ≈ 1 µm.  It is typically a bit hard to identify which part of which object you are referring to at the micrometre level.  In other words, 11 places of decimals is at least 3 too many (8 places would be approximately millimetre), and probably 6 too many (5 places would give you metre accuracy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (it assumes that your floats will have at most 10 decimal places, otherwise adjust the values in STR).

```
WITH MyData (ID, Latitude, Longitude)
AS
(
    SELECT 'A', CAST(33.11 AS FLOAT), CAST(-55.2235 AS FLOAT) UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 33.6407760431,-87.0002760543 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 42.2997,-70.9081 
)
SELECT ID, Latitude, Longitude, 
    LEN(CAST(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(STR([Latitude], 13, 11), CHARINDEX('.', STR([Latitude], 13, 11)) + 1, 20)) AS INT)) AS LatText  
FROM MyData
```

As others have note, however, FLOATs are likely to give you some headaches.
Consider this for instance:

```
SELECT STR(33.11, 20,17) -- result: 33.1099999999999990
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  The number of decimal places is determined by the size of a float in SQL.  How many you SEE is determined by the way the float is formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Use DECIMAL not FLOAT:

```
DECLARE @a FLOAT = 33.6407760431
SELECT CAST(@a AS VARCHAR(100))

DECLARE @b DECIMAL(22,10) = 33.6407760431
SELECT CAST(@b AS VARCHAR(100))
```

Returns:

```
33.6408

33.6407760431
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast as numeric(maxprecision, maxscale). Then iterate with a case statement.

```
declare @value as numeric(19,5) = 123.12647

select 
CASE WHEN @value = round(@value,0) then 0
     WHEN @value = round(@value,1) then 1
     WHEN @value = round(@value,2) then 2
     WHEN @value = round(@value,3) then 3
     WHEN @value = round(@value,4) then 4
     else 5 end
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be valid tsql, but it will be close:

```
SELECT LENGTH(CONVERT(varchar(255), Latitude - CAST (Latitude as int))) AS decimal_place_count
```

Comment: This concept won't work because the CONVERT(varchar(255), Latitude) chops it off at four decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `STR` function instead of `CONVERT` or `CAST`. It allows you more control on the number of decimals and the total length of the string. See [STR (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx)

```
LEN(RTRIM(REPLACE(STR(Latitude,15,10),'0',' '))) - 5
```